# Не могу установить Envoy на Mac os (Command not found)

Tags: laravel, composer, развертывание

Всем привет. Хотел сделать деплой проекта на хостинг и столкнулся с проблемой установки envoy на сам Mac.
Устанавливал этой командой `composer global require laravel/envoy`. Потом после того как пишу в терминал `envoy`, мне выдаёт `-bash: envoy: command not found`. Направьте пожалуйста что почитать или помогите решить. Пока не знаю как решить данную проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было просто добавить его в переменную $PATH. Пользовался этой ссылкой: https://professor-falken.com/ru/mac/como-anadir-una-nueva-ruta-a-la-variable-path-en-tu-mac/

Всё из-за невнимательности. В документации написано `Не забудьте поместить каталог ~/.composer/vendor/bin в вашу переменную PATH, чтобы исполняемый файл envoy мог быть найден при запуске команды envoy в терминале.`, а я не сделал этого